# How to update the svn properties but not all files of a folder

Tags: svn, properties

In my coding environment I've got a dev, test and production machine. Sometimes I have to add files to svn:ignore for all machines. But if I want to update these properties, I have to make an update on a whole folder instead of only some stable files.

Is there any chance to get only the update of the folder properties (like svn:ignore) but without updating all the new and maybe instable files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`svn update --depth empty <path>` will do that.

The deprecated `svn update --non-recursive <path>` suggested in a different answer also updates the directory-contents too; just like you suspected.

Comment: If you use the `--depth` setting on a commit, it will remain set that way and future commits will not include folder contents.  This is fixed by doing another commit with `--depth infitity`.

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like you would like to update the properties of a folder but not the file in that folder. I think that is not possible.

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking for.

Answer (score -1):

`svn update --non-recursive <foldername>`

Comment: And that will not update the files in the specific folder, but only the properties? I would expect that this command will update all files in the folder and it's properties but not the subfolders.